# How to intercept multiple warnings from a Python function?

Tags: python, warnings

Here's a bit of Python pseudocode to illustrate a problem (I'm working in Python 3.8, although I doubt that matters much):

```
import warnings
from some_library import function, LibraryWarning  # (a library that I do not control)

warning_log = []
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("error")
    try:
        result = function()
    except LibraryWarning as w:
        warning_log.append(w)
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
            result = function()
```

The main purpose of this code is to produce `result` without any warnings cluttering up the screen.  It accomplishes that.  However, I also want to document any warnings that occur for later review.  This code accomplishes that too, provided that `function()` only generates one warning.  However, sometimes `function()` produces TWO warnings.  Since I have to switch to ignoring warnings to get `result`, I never see the second warning and I can't append it to my log.

How can I perform a full accounting of all warnings generated, while still obtaining my final
result?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Have you tried looking into logging.captureWarnings? https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings

Comment: @jrmylow: Yes, I have looked at the `logging` module.  The code that I wrote using `logging` also only succeeded in intercepting the first of the two errors -- or, I had to clutter the screen with unwanted warning messages -- or, I intercepted no warnings at all.  I will continue to attempt to use `logging` if someone can confirm that I can achieve my objectives that way.

Comment: would you be able to edit your post with the attempt at the logging code? maybe it's an easier fix to work on that instead of the current posted code

Comment: aside from the use of logging/warnings, I'm just looking over your code and it would seem that there are two issues. The first is if you catch `LibraryWarning` the first time, the second `result = function()` is unprotected by the try/except block. The second issue is that if `function()` is computationally expensive (or produces side-effects), calling it repeatedly may introduce unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I'm aware of the potential issues that may arise when repeating a function call.  I'm confident that the function that I'm working with doesn't have side effects, but of course I would prefer not to waste the time re-running it from the start.  Concerning the use of `logging`, if I can put together a clear, minimal example I will post it.  Probably in another thread.  I'll post a link here if I do.

Answer (score -1):

```
def a_warning_function():
 warning_log = []
 with warnings.catch_warnings():
     warnings.simplefilter("error")
     try:
        result = function()
        return result
    except LibraryWarning as w:
        warning_log.append(w)
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
            result = function()
            return result
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  How does encapsulating my code inside a function change anything?  It would still intercept and log the first LibraryWarning.  Then it would switch to ignoring warnings, try again, and finish without logging the second LibraryWarning.

I have contemplated intercepting stderr and parsing the text.  That is a lot less satisfying and more complicated than catching warnings.

Comment: Hm maybe misunderstood the behaviour would a try / catch / finally work?  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html